# Bubble sort not working at all, if statement not executing

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I'm working on a program which is going to be used to sort students test scores and eventually retrieve the mean, median, and the mode of the scores. For some strange reason my bubble sort is not working.. I'm unsure why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>
#define N 3

int main (void)
{

char vStudents[N][15], trans = 'y', vTemp2;
int vScores[N], vTemp, x, i = 0, j=0, NewN;

printf("\t\tWhatsamatta U Scores System\n\n");

do
{
    printf("Please Enter Students Name: ");
    gets(vStudents[i]);
    trans = 'N';
    while (trans == 'N')
    {
        printf("Enter Students Score: ");
        scanf("%d", &vScores[i]);
        fflush(stdin);

        if (vScores[i] >= 0 & vScores[i] <= 100)
            trans = 'y';
        else 
            printf("Score is invalid, please re-enter score.\n");
    }
    i++;
    j++;
} while (j != N);


for(x = 0; x < N - 1; x++)
{   
    if ((x < N - 1) && (vScores[i] > vScores[i + 1]))
    {
        vTemp = vScores[i];
        vScores[i] = vScores[i + 1];
        vScores[i + 1] = vTemp;
        x = -1;
    }
}

printf("%d %d %d\n\n", vScores[0], vScores[1], vScores[2]);

system("Pause");
return 0;
```

Any help would be useful, thanks in advance!

Comment: Since you use visual studio, have you tried visual studio's very good debugger to step through it line by line and examine variables?

Comment: Yes I have tried that, but the debugger skips over the section where the bubble sort is. It shows the beginning of the for loop, but jumps straight to the printf at the bottom.

Comment: The debugger does not lie. That means your for loop did not get executed at all. Perhaps the condition for the for loop to execute was false the first time.

Comment: Well the loop executes now, but the if statement doesn't. I'm unsure why, because what is required by the if is true

Comment: I would suggest that if the if statement does not execute, the condition is evaluating to false

Answer (score 4):

At least one error:

```
for(x = 0; x < vScores[N] - 1; x++)
{   
   if ((x < vScores[N] - 1) && (vScores[N] > vScores[N + 1]))
   {
```

should be

```
 for(x = 0; x <N - 1; x++)
 {   
    if ((x < N - 1) && (vScores[N] > vScores[N + 1]))
    {
     //^^you should not compare index x with array elements
```

Answer (score 1):

N is always 3. if we replace N in your code with 3, does it still make sense?

```
for(x = 0; x < vScores[3] - 1; x++)
{   
    if ((x < vScores[3] - 1) && (vScores[3] > vScores[3 + 1]))
    {
        vTemp = vScores[3];
        vScores[3] = vScores[3 + 1];
        vScores[3 + 1] = vTemp;
        x = -1;
    }
}
```

Ok, now that it is this:

```
for(x = 0; x < N - 1; x++)
{   
    if ((x < N - 1) && (vScores[i] > vScores[i + 1]))
    {
        vTemp = vScores[i];
        vScores[i] = vScores[i + 1];
        vScores[i + 1] = vTemp;
        x = -1;
    }
}
```

Ask, when does `i` change?

Comment: Thanks! I've done this already, possibly 5 or 6 minutes ago, but the bubble sort still isn't being executed.. I guess I should update the code real quick